# Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters? (I need to find the bug in code I wrote)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

Please help as this is getting on my nerves I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and have tried trace code.

Link to problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/

I created a solution using a sliding window. It works on most test cases, but fails for a few (such as `"ad"`). I can't figure out where the bug is. I basically keep track in a dictionary of characters I've seen and the last index I saw them at which gets updated periodically in a loop. I use two indices `i and j`; `i` gets updated when I find a repeat character. I return the max of current max and length of current substring which is `i-j`. Here is my code below:

```py
  class Solution:
        def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
            if len(s) < 2:
                return len(s) 
            m = 1
            i = 0
            j = 1
            d = {}
            d[s[0]] = 0
            while j < len(s):
                if s[j] in d and d[s[j]] >= i:
                    m = max(m, j -i)
                    i = j
                d[s[j]] = j
                j += 1
            return max(m, j - i - 1)
```

Why does this fail for some cases? Example:

"au"

Output
1
Expected
2

Comment: In what cases does it fail? Please provide an error message or expected and real results.

Comment: @yuri added expected output for failed test case "au"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last line should be `return max(m, j - i)`. Because i is the last index we see repeated character. So. We start this index to end of the string.So length is `len(s) - i` . And since `j = len(s)` (while loop ends when `j = len(s)`) so last substring length is `j-i`. not `j-i-1`

And also we are updating i wrong.let's say s = "abcadf". In while loop when we see second "a" ,so j = 3, we should update i = 1, not 3. Because in this case our longest substring will start with "b".So we should update i as `i = d[s[j]] + 1`. So final result:

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        if len(s) < 2:
            return len(s) 
        m = 1
        i = 0
        j = 1
        d = {}
        d[s[0]] = 0
        while j < len(s):
            if s[j] in d and d[s[j]] >= i:
                m = max(m, j -i)
                i = d[s[j]] + 1
            d[s[j]] = j
            j += 1
        return max(m, j - i)
```

Comment: I'm still seeing test cases fail

Comment: At least one other mistake: `i = j`.

Comment: @petertodds Can you write the case failed.Maybe line `if s[j] in d and d[s[j]] >= i:` should be `if s[j] in d :`. Because we should always update last repeated character index i.

Comment: @PolatkanPolat link to problem is https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/ test case "bbbbb" fails

Comment: i realized `if s[j] in d :` wont help.

Comment: Thank you Polatkan! I knew something was off with my code